# Sed replace text

Tags: sed

I need to replace text with single quotes with `sed` and I can't get it to work.  Here is my code; can you help me?

I have a text file with this format:

```
#sometext
$configuration_TEstbk2_bk2_environment12 = 'lalala'
$configuration_TEstbk2_bk2_envoronment12 = 'lalala1'
$configuration_TEstbk2_bk2_staging12 = 'BACKUP 2'
$configuration_waq4faw4f_q4fq4qg4f = 'r234rq43rq4rqr'
$configuration_alice_StagingTEstBk_bk = 'testebk'
$configuration_deployment_overlays_alice_TEStStngDir = 'some'
$configuration_arefgqrqgrq_341q34tq34t = '134t135'
```

And I need to do something like:

```
sed s/$configuration_arefgqrqgrq_341q34tq34t   ='134t135'/$configuration_arefgqrqgrq_341q34tq34t = 'NEWVALUE'/g
```

I have tried with many combinations with `sed` but I can't find one that works.

Comment: Don't you think it'd might be more useful to show us the output you want given that input rather than a script that doesn't work and leave us guessing what it is you want a script to do?

Answer (score 1):

Would this work for you?

```
sed "/\$config_deployment_overlays_alice_arefgqrqgrq_341q34tq34t_staging/s/'134t135'/'NEWVALUE'/" file
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd probably use:

```
sed '/$configuration_arefgqrqgrq_341q34tq34t *=/'"s/'134t135'/'NEWVALUE'/"
```

This uses a mix of single quotes and double quotes at the shell level to get the correct information to `sed`.  The single quotes enclose the search condition for the lines containing `$configuration_arefgqrqgrq_341q34tq34t` followed by some blanks and an equals sign. This avoids the shell expanding what might be a shell variable name (but probably isn't, so the empty string would be substituted).  I then switch to double quotes at the shell level, so that `sed` gets to see the single quotes: it substitutes the value in single quotes with the replacement value, but only on those lines that contain the given configuration parameter name.

I hope users never have to type those configuration parameter names.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose your problem is with the quoting.  You could use complex quoting to make sure everything is in single quotes, except the single quotes which need to be in double quotes:

```
sed 's/$configuration_arefgqrqgrq_341q34tq34t *= *'"'134t135'"'/$configuration_arefgqrqgrq_341q34tq34t = '"'NEWVALUE'/g"
```

... or you could use some temporary variables to make the whole thing more readable, and suitable for inclusion in a single pair of double quotes:

```
directive='$configuration_arefgqrqgrq_341q34tq34t'
oldvalue="'134t135'"
newvalue="'NEWVALUE'"
sed "s/$directive *= *$oldvalue/$directive = $newvalue/g"
```

(If you only expect one match, the `/g` flag is superfluous.)

Answer (score 0):

You can also totally avoid matching quotes by capturing them:

```
sed '/$configuration_arefgqrqgrq_341q34tq34t/{
         s/\(= *.\).*\(.\) *$/\1NEWVALUE\2/
}' input
```

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -r 's/^(\$\S+\s=\s'\'').*('\'')/\1NEWVALUE\2/' file
```